# how to change Accordion content on click the NavDropdown.Item using React js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

i want to change accordion content on clicking the navdropdown menu items using react .i have tried using react-modal . but it didnt work . i dont want the popup . just want to change the accordion content on dropdown menu item click.

Comment: On navdropdown menu click add data in state and use that state to populate the accordion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

have the content of the accordion inside the state
when clicking on navdropdown menu you can update the state